# Linking to user profile through PHP

Tags: php

On my website I've displayed a list of registered users on a members page using echo in PHP. I'd now like to link the names of these users to their profile pages. Is there a way to do this?

My current code:

```
<html>
<title>Find User Info</title>
<body>

<form method="POST">
<p>Type Username: </p><input type="text" name="username"placeholder="Enter Username...">
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search User">
</form>
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(0);

$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "***"); // Establishing Connection with Server
$db = mysql_select_db("****", $connection); // Selecting Database from Server

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accs ORDER BY loginstatus");  //selecting all from table users where username is name that your is loged in
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) 
 { 
echo $row['name'];
}
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$username = $_POST['username'];
$_SESSION['searchuser'] = $username; //setting session username to one from table, this is useful if you login, that restart your browser and than you go in url where is your profile.php... Anyway this is useful :D 
header( 'Location: user.php' ) ;
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The template link is like: mywebsite.com/search/user.php

Comment: The link you gave for users doesn't have any method to identify the actual specific user. Are there any other parameters that the `user.php` page uses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you'll have to do is echo out an `<a>` element with the appropriate parameters for the link.

In your loop where you echo out the name of the user. you can include the `<a>` element definitions and only have the name as the text of the link:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) { 
  $user_name = $row['name'];
  $profile_link = "http://your-cool-site/users/" . $row['id'];
  echo "<a href='" . $profile_link . "' >" . $user_name . "</a>";
}
```

This code assumes that the link to your user page is something like:

```
http://your-cool-site/users/USER_ID
```

Comment: Unfortunately its not like that. We have a template page, not a seperate page for each user.

Comment: Can you please add to your original question the format of the links to your user profile pages?

Comment: I did it reload page.

Comment: Hey, sorry I was unclear with my question. Your answer was correct however the problem is that I have no actual method of identifying a specific user profile. I can only view mine. Is there a way or are there any resources to help me solve this

Answer (score 2):

```
echo '<a href="link_to_profile.php">'.$row['name'].'</a>';
```

is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: Yes but I want a way to show user info once clicking.

Comment: you can send the info by appending it after URL like -
'<a href="link_to_profile.php?email="'.$row['email'].'>'.$row['name'].'</a>';

Comment: or you can create a single page called user_profile which accepts a $_REQUEST['email'] parameter and then use this id to get user information from db and display.